# Code optimization with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to optimize my source code Twig but this does not look very efficient to me.

My code :

```
{% for info in infos %}
  {% set i = 0 %}
  {% if loop.index0 is divisibleby(3) %}

    <div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">

    {% set open = 'yes' %} 

  {% endif %}

  <li class="span4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="#" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>{{ info.titre }}</h4>
        <p>{{ info.text }}</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{# a traduire multi #}Lire</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  {% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) and open == 'yes' %}
    </ul>

    </div>

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

How can I avoid creating so many variables, and using the same condition twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following does not work, but I hope you get the idea:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        {% for info in infos %}
            {% if loop.index0 is divisibleby(3) and loop.index0 != 0 %}
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
            {% endif %}

        <li class="span4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="#" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>{{ info.titre }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ info.text }}</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{# a traduire multi #}Lire</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
       </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I corrected but it works. I just remove the two last lines of your code

Comment: If you do this, then the last ul won't be closed. Rolling back to the previous version.

Comment: But where is the `{% endfor %}` ? I think it should be before the last ul.div.

Comment: The ENFOR is well positioned but if you take away the last two lines, the ul will close only when loop.index0 be divisible by 3. Just try to see

Comment: The two last lines are supposed to close the very last ul / div and this one only. That's why they are out of the `endfor`

Comment: But the tags inside the "if" are also responsible for the closed

Comment: Yes, but they won't be able to close the very last ul. Do you understand why?

Comment: Glad you did, it's a bit convoluted and difficult to explain, but I haven't found any simpler way for the moment.